# Style points using color gradients with QGIS

Tags: qgis, colormap

I need to style a shapefile with a specific color gradient, but considering **absolute** values.
It's point shapefile with values between 0.19 and 0.70 (considering they're in an absolute scale between -1 and 1).

I'm using QGIS 2.14.3.

I've build a color map using Matlab (.svg format based on the cpt-city) but the problem is that the color steps inside the .svg file are divided with percentages.
I can't give the exact value the style/color I need, unless I do that manually, one by one.

I did the trick when using raster data: I've build color ramp with the exact steps and the correspondent color.

Comment: [QGIS User Guide](http://docs.qgis.org/2.14/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/vector_properties.html) is very clear.

Comment: Welcome to gis.stackexchange! Please note that a good question on this site is expected to show some degree of research on your part, i.e. what you have tried and - if applicable - code so far. For more info, you can check our [faq].

Comment: I didn't find the answer in QGIS User Guide.  The shapefiles I'm working on has hundreds of NDVI values and I need to apply the same color code to each one, so equal NDVI values has the same color through different shapefiles.  My guess is to create a .qml or .sld style file with the exact values and the correspondence with the colours, but I was wondering if there's any simple way to to this procedure.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [SVG2ColoR](http://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/SVG2ColoR/) plugin.

(1) Start the **SVG2ColoR** plugin and read your .svg file from Matlab. I did not have such a sample, so I visited [cpt-city](http://soliton.vm.bytemark.co.uk/pub/cpt-city/index.html) and obtained rainbow color (just because it has plenty ~ 239 colors!) by <kbd>Get URL</kbd>.

[image]

(2) Then I clicked on <kbd>Import</kbd> which imports color into QGIS. In QGIS raster layer properties, I colored a dummy raster (its **Min** and **Max** values are quite important, though).  Classes set to 50 (colors).

[image]

(3) Then I save my `50-colors` rainbow as new style (.qml) file by <kbd>Style</kbd> -> `Save Style`.

(4) I have new qml file which defines 50 colors, each color corresponds to discrete values.

[image]

I used QGIS 2.18, but this plugin was first published in 2014. Should work for QGIS 2.14, too.